# How to use two morris bar on same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, morris.js

Using a morris bar on tabs bydefault first tab morris bar are showing when tab is changed when morris bar is not showing, ids are different on both two morris bar

```
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs tab-demo-active z-depth-1 cyan">
     <li class="tab col s3"><a class="white-text waves-effect waves-light active" href="#today">Today</a>
     </li>
     <li class="tab col s3"><a class="white-text waves-effect waves-light" href="#yesterday">Yesterday</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="today" class="col s12   lighten-4">
   <div class="col s12 m12 l12 card-panel">
     <div id="morris-bar-chart" class="section">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
            <div class="sample-chart-wrapper">
               <div id="morris-bar" class="graph"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>               
  </div>     
</div>
<div id="yesterday" class="col s12   lighten-4">
 <div class="col s12 m12 l12 card-panel">
   <div id="morris-bar-chart" class="section">
     <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
        <div class="sample-chart-wrapper">
          <div id="morris-bar1" class="graph"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>               
   </div>
 </div>
```

and morris js code like this

```
$(function() {
 $.ajax({
   url: "today_attendance.php",
   dataType: 'JSON',
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(response)
{ var i=0;
    Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar',
    data: response,
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: ['y', 'z'],
    //labels: [response[0].a, response[0].b]
    labels: ['MOD-1', 'MOD-2']

    }); 
  }
  });

//Get data from today_Attendance file
$.ajax({
url: "today_attendance.php",
dataType: 'JSON',
type: 'POST',
success: function(response)
{ var i=0;
    Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar1',
    data: response,
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: ['y', 'z'],
    //labels: [response[0].a, response[0].b]
    labels: ['MOD-1', 'MOD-2']

    }); 
}
 });
 });
```

Issue is that **Element=morris-bar** is working on tab 1 but tab 2 **Element=morris-bar1** is not working,

Comment: "not working" doesn't tell us much. What debugging have you done? Have you stepped through the code, and checked in your console and network tools for information? Does your ajax request succeed? Does it return the expected data? Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Does it work if you disable the tab functionality and display both at once? Possibly it won't render to something which is hidden. Maybe try not loading the chart until the tab is visible.

Comment: @ADyson.. thanks for supporting.. issue is that when I refresh a page so today tab is active and morris is show on today tab perfectly.. when I change to yesterday tab.. morris bar some time show on yesterday tab and some time is not show

Comment: Like I said I think it's likely to be due to the tab being hidden when you create the chart. Try not creating the chart until the tab becomes active.